# Object extending using javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have a source object and I want to update its property value with a new target object and return the source object with modified property. Is there any predefined way in java script I have do this.

```js
var sourceObj = {
    context: {
        from: {
            name: "1",
            street: "2"
        },
        to: {},
        weight: 0
    }
}

var targetObj = {
    name: "3",
    street: "4"
}

var result = {
    context: {
        from: {
            name: "1",
            street: "2"
        },
        to: {
            name: "3",
            street: "4"
        },
        weight: 0
    }
}
```

Comment: sourceObj.context.to = targetObj ? not sure if I understand your question

Comment: this is what you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: sourceObj.context.to will throw undefined and we can't assign a targetObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reuse the objects, it's literally:

```
sourceObj.context.to = targetObj;
// (Then don't use `result`)
```

If you want to make shallow copies:

```
result = Object.assign({}, sourceObj);
result.context.to = Object.assign({}, targetObj);
```

Live Example:

```js
var sourceObj = {
    context: {
        from: {
            name: "1",
            street: "2"
        },
        to: {},
        weight: 0
    }
}

var targetObj = {
    name: "3",
    street: "4"
}

var result = Object.assign({}, sourceObj);
result.context.to = Object.assign({}, targetObj);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you want to make deep copies, I leave it as an exercise to the reader based on the above. :-)

E.g., [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) makes shallow copies of objects.

There's also a [Stage 3 proposal for rest/spread properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) which we could use for this (it's likely to make the ES2018 spec, it's already implemented in at least two JavaScript engines):

```
result = {...sourceObj};
result.context.to = {...targetObj};
```

Live Example *(requires a cutting-edge browser)*:

```js
var sourceObj = {
    context: {
        from: {
            name: "1",
            street: "2"
        },
        to: {},
        weight: 0
    }
}

var targetObj = {
    name: "3",
    street: "4"
}

var result = {...sourceObj};
result.context.to = {...targetObj};
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: @HassanImam: Thanks. The weird indentation of the question made me think `to` was supposed to be on the outer layer. I'll fix it.

Comment: Sorry, its my bad on the indentation.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have added my version with bit of explanation expanding on your solution idea. :)

Comment: @DeepakRanjanJena: Meh, I should have read more closely. Fixed, and added live examples.

Comment: @DeepakRanjanJena: They **aren't** ES6. That's just array spread/rest. *Property* spread/rest are, as the answer says, a Stage 3 proposal, but are already in Chrome and Firefox and will almost certainly be in the next spec snapshot (ES2018).

Answer (score 0):

You can shallow copy object with `Object.assign()` and then alter the `to` value by directly accessing the key `to`.

```js
var sourceObj = { context: { from: { name: "1", street: "2" }, to:{}, weight: 0 }};
var targetObj = { name: "3", street: "4" };
var result = Object.assign({},sourceObj);
result.context.to = Object.assign({},targetObj);
console.log(result);
```

Alternatively, you can directly update the `to` key of `sourceObj`. But that will modify your `sourceObj` object.

```js
var sourceObj = { context: { from: { name: "1", street: "2" }, to:{}, weight: 0 }};
var targetObj = { name: "3", street: "4" };
sourceObj.context.to = targetObj;
console.log(sourceObj);
```